# jQuery UI Button - Text beneath the Custom Icon

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-button

I am trying to create a jQuery UI button with a custom icon on the top of the text. The default behavior creates icon on the left/right of the text but I want the icon to be on the top! Can this be done? If so, your help/guidance is greatly appreciated.

Also, how can one have a 32x32 size Custom Icon (even increasing the height of the button didn't help and was stripping the icon). Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<button id="btnSave">Save</button>
```

JS:

```
$('#btnSave').button({
    icons: {primary: "saveIcon"}
});
```

CSS:

```
.saveIcon {
    background-image: url(../images/Save.png) !important;
}
```

Comment: Brock, thanks for your reply. Do you mind giving an example as I am not able to get this working using overlay! TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this bit of CSS ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/BKxpx/11/)):

```
.ui-button-icon-primary.ui-icon.saveIcon {
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    margin: 10px 0 2em -16px; 
    text-align: center;
    left: 50%;
    top: 5px;
    background-image: url(../images/Save.png) !important;
}
.ui-button-text-icon-primary .ui-button-text {
    display: block;
    position: static;
    padding: 50px 10px 5px 10px;
}
```

Comment: Updated the CSS and demo to automatically center the icon over the text.

Comment: Works but to work with different buttons and to remove the "!important" change ".ui-button-icon-primary.ui-icon.saveIcon" and ".ui-button-text-icon-primary .ui-button-text" to "#widey > span.ui-icon" and "#widey > span.ui-button-text" (for a button with id="widey").